# Traefik is not loading my config file at all

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

As the title says my traefik container is not loading my config file. I have a folder with my `docker-compose.yml` and my `traefik.yml`. According to the traefik documentation traefik will automatically search for a file with this name in the working directory but it does not load it.

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.3'

services: 
  traefik:
  image: traefik
  ports:
    - 8080:8080
    - 80:80
    - 443:443
```

and my `traefik.yml`:

```
api:
  dashboard: true
  insecure: true

entryPoints:
  web:
    address: ":80"
  websecure:
    address: ":443"
```

I expect that the dashboard is avalible under localhost:8080 and that it shows my entrypoints.

I hope that you can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so after looking at some other examples it seems that you can mount your config files to the container using `volumes` and it will work absolutely fine.

Please have a look at the configuration below `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.3'

services: 
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./traefik.yaml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yaml
```